# Polymer 1.x: How to filter iron-data-table?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, plunker, iron-data-table, polymer-1.x

How do I add a `filter` attribute to `<iron-data-table`? (Please post a plunk demo.)

[I forked this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/wiuFK2vm6bKL53BcYbHW?p=preview). Then I tried to add a filter by adding the following line:

```
<iron-data-table
  ...
  filter="['item.user.name.first.length', '< 5']">
```

Which broke the plunk. [Here is the new (now broken) plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5h7vPBnpj32olbHjvmYu?p=preview).

[The documentation here describes the `filter` attribute as follows](https://saulis.github.io/iron-data-table/#iron-data-table):

> `filter` An array containing path/filter value pairs that are used to filter the items.

But it lacks an example of how to use it.

How do I add a `filter` attribute to `<iron-data-table`? (Please post a plunk demo.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a very well documented feature:

Normally, you would go about using `filter-by` and `filter-value` properties in `<data-table-column>` elements, but you can also access the `filter` property directly.

When it comes to filtering `items` data source, there is only "contains" kind of filtering available. So, you pretty much can't do filtering based on string length like in your Plnkr with those. For more custom filtering functionality, you need to go using a function `dataSource` where you can do anything you want using the filters provided as arguments for the data source function.

Anyways, in case you want still to access `filter` directly and for example provide a default filtering value, you need to set the value to be an array of objects, which have a `path` and `filter` property:

`this.filter = [{path: 'user.name.first', filter: 'donna'}];`

Here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/KIefwLNHeinkOgERWOvZ?p=preview

Comment: +1. But how do I implement the `dataSource` function you describe? [Here is my specific question to that effect](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40250746/1640892).