# Polymer 1.x: How to use dataSource function to filter iron-data-table?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, plunker, iron-data-table, polymer-1.x

[Here is the Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/cGykY65HWnK4pIQ0qx8O?p=preview).

I want to implement the `dataSource` filtering function for `<iron-data-table` [as described in the accepted answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40232809/1640892). My problem is [the docs here do not give an example of how to accomplish this](https://github.com/Saulis/iron-data-table/blob/master/iron-data-table.html).

Eventually, I will want to have a complex set of filters (think: *control panel*) on a large data set of items.

I have tried copying the approach employed by `dom-repeat` [described in the docs here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-repeat) but without success.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cGykY65HWnK4pIQ0qx8O?p=preview

```
<iron-data-table
    items="[[users.results]]"
    data-source="source(item)">
...
    source: function(item) {
      return item.user.name.first.length > 6;
    },
```

How do I correctly implement the `dataSource` property function to filter the items of `<iron-data-table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataSource` property takes a function as a value, so the most straight-forward way is to define a function property in your parent element and use normal Polymer bindings to pass that down.

The function signature isn't unfortunately very well defined, but there are some examples in the `iron-data-table` demo pages: http://saulis.github.io/iron-data-table/demo/ (remote data example)

I've updated your Plunkr accordingly: http://plnkr.co/edit/VWIAvWAnuf2aiCjJjCdI?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the code in the accepted answer is as follows:

http://plnkr.co/edit/VWIAvWAnuf2aiCjJjCdI?p=preview

```
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/iron-data-table+Saulis+:master/components/">
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

<link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">

<link rel="import" href="iron-data-table/iron-data-table.html">

<dom-module id="content-el">
    <template>
        <style></style>

    <iron-ajax
      auto
      url="https://saulis.github.io/iron-data-table/demo/users.json" 
      last-response="{{users}}">
    </iron-ajax>
    <iron-data-table
        data-source="[[dataSource]]">
      <data-table-column name="Picture" width="50px" flex="0">
        <template>
          <img src="[[item.user.picture.thumbnail]]">
        </template>
      </data-table-column>
      <data-table-column name="First Name">
        <template>[[item.user.name.first]]</template>
      </data-table-column>
      <data-table-column name="Last Name">
        <template>[[item.user.name.last]]</template>
      </data-table-column>
      <data-table-column name="Email">
        <template>[[item.user.email]]</template>
      </data-table-column>
    </iron-data-table>

    </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      Polymer({
        is: 'content-el',

        properties: {
          users: Array,
          dataSource: Function
        },

        observers: ['_usersChanged(users)'],

        _usersChanged: function(users) {
          this.dataSource = function(params, callback) {
            var filteredUsers = users.results.filter(function(item) {
              return item.user.name.first.length > 6;
            });

            callback(filteredUsers, filteredUsers.length);   
          };
        }
      });
        })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```